# Show 0 value in bar or column chart

Tags: bar-chart, ssrs-2008-r2

In this screen shot from an SSRS report with bar charts, I would like for 0 values to display a tiny bit of color rather than just being blank. Here's what it looks like now:

[image: Bar chart showing 100% and 0%]

Most of these charts have many series. I am generating a copy of the charts for each person under review and including the comparison values for everyone else in the group. I am thus coloring the bar representing the person under review differently from the normal color so they can easily see their performance compared to others.

Now, while there are y-axis labels, I would also like the 0 value to have at least a tiny sliver of color so everything is symmetric and the color can be seen. (I am also thinking about putting those with no data at all in the chart and need a way to distinguish those, so any ideas on how to accomplish that would help as well.)

I thought about making the axis start at -1 so the space from -1 to 0 would be colored, but I can't figure out how to get the labels to start at 0 (as shown) when I do this. I have played with quite a few settings and nothing is coming out right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sigh. I just figured it out.

Select the X axis.

- Set `CrossAt` and `Minimum` properties to -1.
- Set the `IntervalOffset` property to 1.

Important note: the chart in Design mode will NOT show correctly. Since I put an `Interval` of 20, it is showing `-1 19 39 59 79 99`, but when I actually Preview the report, the result is correct. Don't let yourself be thrown off by the design-mode pre-preview.

Now it looks like this:

[image: bar chart with 0% showing]

If you leave out the `CrossAt` property, then the bars float away from the y-axis, leaving a gap. You must use all the properties I mentioned above to make the color reach past 0 all the way to the axis line.

Comment: If label is integer intervals, you also should set "LabelIntervalOffset" to 1 in order to begin numbering a 0 as expected. I'm using this solution because , if count is one, the bar does not show on the chart unless CrossAt -11 is used.